# How to control the tool icons for the ExtJS accordion

Tags: extjs4

If I make a TreePanel collapsible, the tool icons are up and down double arrows.

In an accordion, they switch to being +/-.

How can I use the double arrows for the accordion?

(version 4.1.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found an answer:

```
/* Undo the accordion's bizarre switch to +/- */
.x-accordion-hd .x-tool-expand-top,
.x-accordion-hd .x-tool-collapse-top {
    background-position: 0 -210px;
}

.x-accordion-hd .x-tool-expand-bottom,
.x-accordion-hd .x-tool-collapse-bottom {
    background-position: 0 -195px;
}
```

For reasons known to Sencha's designers, the accordion is always styled with +/-. The above fixes it. I'm sure that this is fragile and should be replaced by something done with their theming CSS compiler.